# How to make link in div clickable under another div, but do not change div width?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index, clickable

How to make link-1 in div clickable under another div, but do not change div width?

```css
div {
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
text-align: right;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="http://link">Link-1</a>

</div>

<div>
<a href="http://link">link-2</a>

</div>
```

Comment: You mean to put both links in the same div?

Comment: No, the links should remain in different divs but be clickable

Comment: The issue is because you added position absolute to the div's/ So they will be coming on top of each other, hence only one will be clickable at a time

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, both the divs are positioned absolutely, so the second div is overlapping the first div. To position both divs next to each other, it would be a better idea to use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). This way, you can add content to each div that doesn't overlap.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 
 .container div {
  width: 50%;
 }
 
 div:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem, the div's are covering eachother, which makes it kinda impossible, i would put them in a container and make two colums and that way you still have the border around it